# Rails has_many through with where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following associations in my Survey model:

```
has_many :survey_group_lists, -> { order 'sequence ASC, group_id ASC' }
has_many :groups, through: :survey_group_lists
```

I want to add where cluase to :groups association so it will return only active groups. I've tried something like this:

```
has_many :groups, -> { where(active: true) }, through: :survey_group_lists
```

but it returns me an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "slide_groups"
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Edit: I'm using Rails 5.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? We're having the exact same problem over here, and still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 9):

```
has_many :groups, -> {where('groups.active' => true)}, through: :survey_group_lists
```

This is correct.

Note that **the lambda has to be the second argument**, otherwise you will see `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>` .

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
has_many :groups, through: :survey_group_lists, -> { where(groups: {active: true}) }
```

Comment: This returns syntax error: `syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

Comment: new line? where did it come from?

Comment: it should be `where('groups.active = ?', true)`

Comment: ohh, thanx @AndreyDeineko, try this and let us know

Comment: still '\n' u mean? strange.. are you sure it is on this line, I doubt it is somewhere else in your code..

Comment: `has_many :groups, through: :survey_group_lists, -> { where(groups: { active: true } ) }`

Comment: The way to get this to work is to put the scope as the second argument. So change the answer to: has_many :groups, -> { where('groups.active' => true) }, through: :survey_group_lists

Comment: @MateuszUrbański does the solution provided above works for you? If yes, I'll update the answer.. :)

Comment: @KevinSylvestre it works, I have used it multiple times..any error you receive?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon unfortunately doesn't work for `preload` or `include` (not sure if you saw that in my original comment). It'll warn `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table`. It is fine for accessing otherwise.

Comment: @KevinSylvestre if that's the case, can you confirm whether the asscoiation is working or not? like for above case `Model.last.groups`?

Comment: Yup - that's fine. Like I mentioned, it is doesn't work for both preload and include.

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
has_many :groups, through: :survey_group_lists, -> { where(groups: { active: true } ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
has_many :survey_group_lists, -> { order 'sequence ASC, group_id ASC' }
has_many :active_survey_groups, -> { where active: true }, class_name: 'survey_group_lists'
has_many :groups, :through => :active_survey_groups
```